# Streaming m3u8 HLS Audio on Android

Tags: android, audio, streaming, m3u8

i've found problems trying to reproduce m3u8 HLS audio streaming on Android. Right now i can reproduce video in m3u8 HLS link with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(contentURL),"video/mp4");                                                        
startActivityForResult(i,0)
```

I've already tried this method:

number 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(contentURL),"video/mp4");                                                        
startActivityForResult(i,0)
```

number 2:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(contentURL),"audio/mp3");                                                        
startActivityForResult(i,0)
```

number 3:

```
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http:\\testexample.m3u8"));
  mediaPlayer.start();
```

In case 3 the error on log like "mediaserver Died", in case 1 and 2 simply the phone gallery said "can't reproduce video" or "can't reproduce this kind of file".
Last but not the least, if i send the http m3u8 link with an email at a Nexus 4 with Android 4.3, it open the link with chrome, then ask to open phone galleryplayer, and reproduce it. The same thing done with da SII with cyanogenmod and android 4.2.1 said, as before, "cannot reproduce video".

Comment: In Android 2.3 & 3.0, you have to use httplive:// scheme, in 3.1 use http://. What version of android are you testing in?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your code In try-catch block.
2. Set onPreparedListenet() and prepareAsync(), then on the onPrepared() callback start playback.